# Catch System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have a piece of code in a listbox_SelectedIndexChanged event :

```
try
{
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
    btnRemove.Enabled = false;
    btnProcess.Enabled = false;
    btnCancelProcess.Enabled = false;
}
catch { }
```

The list is constantly populated/unpopulated by another process, and sometimes, on the first line `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();`, I get an unhandled `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`.

I saw other posts here where people had `catch (Exception ex)` and others advised to catch everything, as Win32 are not .NET exceptions, but here I'm willing to catch all exceptions ...

I don't have to process the exception, the list constantly evolves, the piece of code will be next executed again, I just want my app not to crash!

How can I prevent to fail on this particular exception?

Comment: Are you sure you don't fail earlier in the code. Because I don't see any code that could produce an Expection in your try{}.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? btw, if you're clearing and filling on the other thread; you might want to consider a lock

Comment: Are the controls that are removed correctly disposed? Each control creates User Objects which persist until the control is disposed and there is a limit of 10000 user objects per application. You can check in the task manager whether this is the cause of your exception.

Comment: `Win32Exception` is basically translation of Win32 error codes so it's not so simple to diagnose what is happening without the corresponding error code.

Comment: I try to translate because my errors are displayed in french. The exact error is "Error while creating the window handle". Native error code is 1158. Maximum number of disposed objects is less than 1000 at the time it fails, I'm absolutely certain. And yes, I'm absolutely certain it fails on the first line in the try block, as each time Visual Studio highlights this line when it fails.
When executing in "Release" mode outside of Visual Studio, the application crashes without the usual exception dialog. I have the regular Windows crash dialog.

Comment: Regarding threads, other threads are updating the listbox using "invoke" method, because the UI only works on a single thread. Then, the listbox (regular control) handles its SelectedIndexChanged event, I thought could only be done on the UI thread, right? And, it could not be the issue, otherwise it would fail immediately. But my issue is intermitent. Sometimes it doesn't fail at all for an hour, sometimes after some minutes.